# Using a callback only when a filter returns boolean value true

Tags: javascript, jquery

using the filter function with the following code:

```
tabs = ['GP_0_Result_', 'GP_Scores', 'LGP_Scores'];
        
gp = [];
gp[0] = new Object();
gp[0].round = [];
gp[0].round[0] = new Object();      // gp[0].round[0].activeTabs = ['GP_0_Result_', 'SGP_Scores', 'BBC'];
gp[0].round[0].activeTabs = [];
        
$fn_removeTabs = function($fn_rebuildTabs){
    gp[0].round[0].activeTabs = gp[0].round[0].activeTabs.filter(function(val, i){
        a = (tabs.indexOf(val.substring(0,16)) == -1 ? true : false);
        return a;
    });
    
    // Only call ** $fn_rebuildTabs(gp[0].round[0].activeTabs[0]); ** if true is returned from the filter;
    $fn_rebuildTabs(gp[0].round[0].activeTabs[0]);
    return gp[0].round[0].activeTabs;
};
        
$fn_rebuildTabs = function(a0){
    //alert(">>>> "+gp[0].round[0].activeTabs+" | "+a0+" **** ");
    a0 = gp[0].round[0].activeTabs.length;                          
    gp[0].round[0].activeTabs.push(gp[0].round[0].activeTabs[0]);
};
```

I only want to use the callback should a true value be returned from the filter function.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

** Yes this is the line I want to know the result from once the filter function is complete:

```
a = (tabs.indexOf(val.substring(0,16)) == -1 ? true : false);
```

Ideally I will be left with a variable stating the value true or false;

Thanks again.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more semantically correct to check whether `activeTabs` has anything in it? Why rely on secondary logic?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Array.isArray(gp[0].round[0].activeTabs) && gp[0].round[0].activeTabs.length > 0)
    $fn_rebuildTabs(gp[0].round[0].activeTabs[0]);
```

Looks like a simple if check should suffice